# bash - loop through subdirectories, cat files and rename with directory name

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder structure like this ...

```
data/
---B1/
name_x_1.gz
name_y_1.gz
name_z_2.gz
name_p_2.gz
---C1
name_s_1.gz
name_t_1.gz
name_u_2.gz
name_v_2.gz
```

I need to go in to each subdirectory (e.g. B1) and perform the following:

```
cat *_1.gz > B1_1.gz
cat *_2.gz > B1_2.gz
```

I'm having problems with the file naming part. I can get in directories using the following:

```
for d in */; do      
cat *_1.gz > $d_1.gz
cat *_2.gz > $d_2.gz   
done
```

However I get an error that $d is a directory -- how do I strip the name to create the concatenated filename?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you create a **copy** of the files in your actual code, but say that you want to **rename** them in the title of your question?

Comment: How can you have two files with the same name in one directory? (E.g. there are two "name_1.gz" files in every directory)

Comment: i want to combine files that have the same extension within folders (e.g. *_1.gz and *_2.gz) and rename with their directory name e.g. B1_1.gz and B1_2.gz

Comment: @Dominique I will clarify this in the code ... they are not exactly the same filename ... just same extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're calling [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you can use parameter expansion and do everything natively in the shell without creating a sub-shell to another process.  This is POSIX compliant

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in data/*; do
  cat "$dir/"*_1.gz > "$dir/${dir##*/}_1.gz"
  cat "$dir/"*_2.gz > "$dir/${dir##*/}_2.gz"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking your question verbatim: If you have a variable `d`, where you know that it ends in `/` (as is the case in your example), you can get the value with this last character stripped by writing `${d:0:-1}` (i.e. the substring starting at the beginning, up to (excluding) the last character.

Of course in your case, I would rather write the loop as

```
for d in *; do
```

which already creates the names **without** a trailing slash. But this is still probably not what you want, because `d` would assume the name of the **entries** in the directory you have cd'ed to, but you want the **name** of the directory itself. You can optain this for instance by `$(basename "$PWD")`, which turns your loop into (i.e.)

```
cd B1
prefix=$(basename "$PWD") # This set prefix to B1
for f in * 
do
  # Since your original code indicates that you want to create a *copy* of the file
  # with a new name, I do the same here.
  cp -v "$f" "${prefix}_$f" #      
done
```

You can also use `cat`, as in your original solution, if you prefer.

Comment: I need to concatenate 2 files with the same end of file ... e.g. within that directory there will always be 2 files names _1.gz and those need to be concatenated together

Comment: For catenating several files, you need of course `cat`.  But then, I don't understand why you are looping over all files from your directory after the `cd B1` in your code.

Comment: I was just showing how I would do it for each individual folder ... e.g. cd into a directory ... perform cat ... but I guess it was confusing, I have edited

Comment: @R-MASHup : In this case, I suggest that you remove the word _rename_ from the title of your question, as it is confusing. No renaming is going on here.

Comment: I am renaming files ... going from name_x_1.gz to directory_name_1.gz

Comment: Your code still doesn't make sense to me. What is the `for` loop supposed to do? Basically you want to take a **group** of files (say, all those with namens ending in `_2.gz`), and make a new file out of this group. But this is a completely different problem than asking, how to strip the finals `/` from a variable. I don't see how you would group these files.

Comment: @R-MASHup : This creates a new file, directory_name_1.gz, but the old ones are still here. Therefore, we don't call the process _renaming_. With your approach, you will end up with more files in the directory than have been initially. This is not renaming.

Comment: Just a question: for x in *, doesn't that include current and parent directory as well instead of just the files?

Comment: It contains all non-hidden entries of the current directory. Since the current directory is `.` and the parent directory is `..`, they are not contained in the explansion for `*`. Likeways, an entry '.foo.gz` would not be contained.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just descend into the directory.

```
# assuming PWD = data/
for d in */; do
   (
       cd "$d"
       cat *_1.gz > "$(basename "$d")"_1.gz
       cat *_2.gz > "$(basename "$d")"_2.gz
   )
done
```

> how do I strip the name to create the concatenated filename?

The simplest and most portable is with `basename`.

Comment: Perhaps `cd "$d"|| exit`, or protecting it with `if [[ -d "$d]" ]]`?

Comment: Sure - that would be advisable to do when someone would want to protect against the case where there are no directories in the current directory.

Comment: Right! I missed the fact that appending a `/` restricts filename generation to those entries which are directories!

Comment: I admit that I didn't know that cd could be used in scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This requires Ed, which should hopefully be present on your machine.  If not, I trust your distribution will have a package for it.

```
#!/bin/sh

cat >> edprint+.txt << EOF
  1p
  q
EOF

cat >> edpop+.txt << EOF
  1d
  wq
EOF

b1="${PWD}/data/B1"
c1="${PWD}/$data/C1"

find "${b1}" -maxdepth 1 -type f > b1stack
find "${c1}" -maxdepth 1 -type f > c1stack

while [ $(wc -l b1stack | cut -d' ' -f1) -gt 0 ]
do
  b1line=$(ed -s b1stack < edprint+.txt)
  b1name=$(basename "${b1line}")
  b1suffix=$(echo "${b1name}" | cut -d'_' -f3)
  b1fixed=$(echo "B1_${b1suffix}"
  mv -v "${b1}/${b1line}" "${b1}/${b1fixed}"
  ed -s b1stack < edpop+.txt
done

while [ $(wc -l c1stack | cut -d' ' -f1) -gt 0 ]
do
  c1line=$(ed -s c1stack < edprint+.txt)
  c1name=$(basename "${c1line}")
  c1suffix=$(echo "${c1name}" | cut -d'_' -f3)
  c1fixed=$(echo "B1_${c1suffix}"
  mv -v "${c1}/${c1line}" "${c1}/${c1fixed}"
  ed -s c1stack < edpop+.txt
done

rm -v ./edprint+.txt
rm -v ./edpop+.txt
rm -v ./b1stack
rm -v ./c1stack
```